# Summing moments and Riemann zeta values

Tags: nt.number-theory, real-analysis, integration, moments

Let $d\mu_n(x)=\cos^{2n}x\,dx$ and consider the averages of moments
$$\alpha_n=\frac{\int_0^{\pi/2}x^4d\mu_n(x)}{\int_0^{\pi/2}d\mu_n(x)}.$$
Then, I have encountered a curious evaluation
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^2(\alpha_{n-1}-\alpha_n)
=\frac{21}8\zeta(4)-\frac32\zeta(2);$$
where $\zeta(s)$ is the Riemann zet function.

> Is this true?

Comment: This question is straightforward to reformulate in terms of Euler sums, the rest is a routine technical calculation.

Comment: the right-hand-side equals a sum of $\pi^2$ and $\pi^4$ (with rational coefficients) --- any reason to write this in terms of Zeta functions?

Comment: @CarloBeenakker: I'm hoping for (possible) generalization.

Comment: How did you "encounter" your identity without "proving" it?

Comment: @GHfromMO: This came out of some calculations, then I "guessed" the answer would be in powers of $\pi$. After some fishing, the rational coefficients I managed.

Comment: @GHfromMO it is very easy to guess that the sum might be a linear combination of zeta functions once the sum is written in terms of Euler sums. The rational coefficients are then guessed by PSLQ algorithm.

Comment: @Nemo: I am not familiar with Euler sums. You seem to know the proof, why don't you give it as an answer?

Comment: @GHfromMO , I know the general algorithm which leads to a proof, but the details are boring. Hope someone will find a short and nice proof and post it as an answer.

Comment: @GHfromMO: We can believe there is a proof, only when we see it.

Comment: Well, belief is a personal and subjective thing, and I can believe whatever I can and want. Anyways, Nemo clarified that (s)he does not have the proof yet, but (s)he believes (s)he can find it!

Comment: @T.Amdeberhan GHfromMO first, $\alpha_n$ can be written in terms of Harmonic numbers, thus the sum under consideration is an [Euler sum](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulerSum.html). There is a lot of literature devoted to finding Euler sums in terms of zeta functions. This is general description of the straightforward head-on approach to this problem. There also might be a nice, short proof. A person motivated in a detailed proof can turn this into an actual proof. Personally I'm not motivated in digging deeper into this problem.

Comment: @Nemo --- I am intrigued by this connection to Harmonic numbers; I wrote an explicit expression for $\alpha_n$ in the answer box; can you help me to see how to write this in terms of $H_n =\sum_{k=1}^n 1/k$ ?

Comment: @CarloBeenakker I find it easier to work from the formula $$\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos^{2n}x\cos bx\,dx=\frac{\pi (2n)!}{2^{2n+1}\Gamma(n+1+b/2)\Gamma(n+1-b/2)}$$ by differentiating it 4 times wrt $b$ and then put $b=0$.

Comment: @Nemo: good suggestion.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After my first failed attempt I now follow the route suggested by Nemo --- which works smoothly.
Starting from Nemo's identities
$$F(b)\equiv\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos^{2n}x\cos bx\,dx=\frac{\pi (2n)!}{2^{2n+1}\Gamma(n+1+b/2)\Gamma(n+1-b/2)}$$
$$\int_0^{\pi/2}x^4\cos^{2n}x\,dx=\lim_{b\rightarrow 0}\frac{d^4}{db^4}F(b),$$
I arrive at
$$\alpha_n=\tfrac{3}{4}\left[ \psi ^{(1)}(n+1)\right]^2-\tfrac{1}{8}\psi ^{(3)}(n+1),$$
where $\psi^{(m)}(x)$ is the [Polygamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygamma_function)
$$\psi^{(m)}(x)=\frac{d^m}{dx^m}\left(\frac{1}{\Gamma(x)}\frac{d}{dx}\Gamma(x)\right),$$
$$\psi^{(m)}(n)=(-1)^{m+1}m!\sum_{k=n}^\infty\frac{1}{k^{m+1}},\;\;m\geq 1,\;\;n\in\mathbb{N}.$$
(The last equation gives the connection to Harmonic numbers mentioned by Nemo.)
The recurrence relation
$$\psi^{(m)}(x+1)=\psi^{(m)}(x)+\frac{(-1)^m m!}{x^{m+1}}$$
implies that
$$\alpha_{n-1}-\alpha_n=\tfrac{3}{2} n^{-2} \psi ^{(1)}(n)-\tfrac{3}{2}n^{-4}.$$
From here we arrive at the result in the OP,
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^2(\alpha_{n-1}-\alpha_n)=\frac{3}{2}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty\frac{1}{k^2(n+1)^2}=\frac{21}8\zeta(4)-\frac32\zeta(2).$$

---

This simple final expression suggests a generalization to higher powers of $x$, but that does not seem to work. If I replace $x^4\cos^{2n}x$ in the definition of $\alpha_n$ by say $x^6\cos^{2n}x$ or $x^8\cos^{2n}x$, I find that $\alpha_{n-1}-\alpha_n$ contains *products* of Polygamma functions, which I have not been able to sum up in closed form.

Comment: Your last sum telescopes to $\alpha_0=\frac{\pi^4}{80}$. Pleasing but trivial... :D

Comment: point taken, thanks, I'll remove this silly last sum.